# QT ModelView: Example of using shared pointers in QAbstractItemModel

Tags: qt

I've been trying to get a class derived from `QAbstractItemModel` working, using objects from a base class I've written (non-Qt) which are shared pointers. So far I wasn't able to make this work. in delegate the data I get out of the modelview using `qvariant_cast<std::shared_ptr<TreeItem>>(index.data())` is basically jumbled. I've looked for an example without success and was wondering if anyone has been able to successfully use `shared_ptr`s with `QAbstractItemModel` and was willing to share their code, an example, a tip, or anything. Below is a shortened edition of related code parts for abruptness.

In `index()` I'm using:

```cpp
parentItem = std::shared_ptr<TreeItem>(static_cast<TreeItem*>(parent.internalPointer()));
std::shared_ptr<TreeItem> childItem
//some logic
return createIndex(row, column, &childItem);
```

In `parent()`, I'm using:

```cpp
auto childItem = qvariant_cast<std::shared_ptr<treeItem>>(child.data());
std::shared_ptr<treeItem> parentItem;
//some logic
return createIndex(parentItem.row(), parentItem.column(), &parentItem);
```

And in `data()`:

```cpp
auto item = std::shared_ptr<TreeItem>(
    static_cast<TreeItem*>(index.internalPointer()));

if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
  return QVariant::fromValue(item);
else
  return QVariant();
```

Note that the `createIndex` could be used with either `const void *ptr` or `quintptr id`.

Comment: Please provide a more complete example

Comment: You are doing `&childItem` in `createIndex()` but in `data()` you cast this to `TreeItem*`. This doesn't make sense as types are totally different. Also `Qt::DisplayRole` is meant for display strings in the interface usually, returning a pointer here makes zero sense

Comment: Yeah, I get the feeling that `&childItem` is not the way to go, I just can figure out what to use instead.

Comment: @Waqar the rest is just the usual implementation, some logic and other irrelevant things. The main question is the `shared_ptr`, how to cast and retrieve it.

Comment: `&childItem` would result in `std::shared_ptr<TreeItem>*` so just cast to that and dereference and then store it.